# MVC 2 button click event not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

This is my code in `Index.aspx` page.

when I click on the button the click event is not getting trigerred.

I am new in `ASP.NET` and `MVC` too..

plz help me out.

Code in Index.aspx

```
protected void LogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginForm.Models.LoginDetails objLogin = new LoginForm.Models.LoginDetails();
        objLogin.Name = (Request.Form["Name"].ToString());
        objLogin.Password = (Request.Form["Password"].ToString());
        if (objLogin.Name == "EMP75" && objLogin.Password == "fin@123")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login/Details");
        }
    }

<asp:Button ID="aa" Text="Login" OnClick="LogIn_Click" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using Asp.net WebForms and not MVC. You might want to check that you've

```
AutoEventWireup="true"
```

at your page level. If it is false, you need to manually wireup all events yourself.

Build your page and check.

Comment: No I am using MVC and i think we need to write the button click event in the index.aspx page iteself..?? Although if i write javascript on onCLientClick property it does get fire and show according to the script added like--  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:alert('hi');" /> it does show 'hi' message on click of the button

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:alert('hi');" /> is in Webforms. MVC don't have server controls.